# How to split a mammoth React application into multiple small modules

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack, single-page-application, code-splitting

Our Team is working on a huge commerce application which is like any other commerce application has several modules. Each module has its own specific team to take care of its coding, testing and  deployment.
Being a Single SPA for all modules we face challenges during deployment like one of the deployment is overridden by other teams. To overcome this we wanted to **split our application into multiple modules yet adhering to SPA model**.
Pointer for the ways of doing this will be greatly appreciated.
 
**Example Scenario:** 
Main application is divided as follows,br/>
Main Application
1) Products
2) Pricing
3) Ordering
4) Fulfillment
5) Returns
and we also have ***Core*** module which is shared among all modules.

Now our challenge is to make sure that individual components are deployed independently without the other.

**Note:** we are using **webpack** for bundling and code splitting across react components.

Answer (score 2):

One thing you can try is..

- Identify all the components that are reusable and create a library like your own company framework.
- And if you want to take it to the next level, you can try NPM private repo and create a separate package for each of your modules. (e.g. Products, Pricing etc). So you will have one main application and all this modules are imported just like you import third-party packages. You can also independently deploy this modules, once it's tested okay, just update package & run npm install. You are good to go :) Sort of microservice architecture with JavaScript.

Answer (score 1):

We did this where work and below are ways we achieved it.

1. Stateful/Container components holds render logic, loads data and listens for changes and stateless components
2. Flatten routes; no unnessarilly nested routes. components that cannot be reached by url are moved as helper components and the logic they handle is kept a small as possible.
3. We use redux for state management
4. All business logic and server calls are handled inside actions. components get processed data and focus on rendering logic

Comment: Thanks Femi. We are also following the above things. In fact we have seaparate folders for each modules and each module folder has its own action, reducers and components. My question was more around the deployment strategy of individual module which keeps it isolated from the other module.

Comment: Oh for that we on a recent project we seperated every sub-component into their own repo publish them as private npm modules and install them into the main module. That however introduced some undesirable development setup when you are working in a sub-component and want to see the changes live in the main component. we also had a bit of issue with react-router navigating between sub-components.

Answer (score 1):

Well.. one way to completely separate out the deployment is if they are separate apps, but that is really hard to keep your dependencies in sync so you don't force your users to download 2 or 3 copies of `react-dom` for example.
It would also lead to a full-page reload on transitions between modules. And you wouldn't be able to share a store as easily.

So instead have separate modules who export a Route configuration and other bits you need such as reducers. And import all of those into a central app that wires it all up.
Then let Webpack do its job and bundle up all of the things.